# Game Maker Studio: Android Error at compile

Tags: android, compiler-errors, game-maker

I've found this error while I'm compiling my program as an Android apk in GameMaker: Studio Pro (v1.4.1567)

```
 BUILD FAILED
 C:\Program Files\Android_SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Program Files\Android_SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:694: null returned: 1
```

How do I fix this? The Android SDK that I'm using is:

```
Android 3.2 (API 13).
```

I know it's obsolete but that is what GameMaker needs. And the NDK:

```
android-ndk-r10e
```

If that helps, Thanks!

Comment: firstly, update GMS to [1.4.1598](http://store.yoyogames.com/downloads/gm-studio/release-notes-studio.html). Then check [this](http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/91625158) and [this](http://help.yoyogames.com/entries/23363366). And also show your full log.

Answer (score 0):

After checking a few things I discovered that 1.4.1567 is the #1 most pirated version of GM:S right now. I'm not accusing you of illegally obtaining Game Maker Studio, but that's the most likely explanation for your problems. If it happens to just be a coincidence and you actually bought it, just update to 1.4.1598 as @Dmi7ry suggested to see if that fixes your problems.

Comment: Yeah, It was from our school professor. He said it can help us start learning game programming. He said that if we like it, BUY IT. But of course, we're just students. Anyway, Thanks! We'll try unity after trying GMS. Thank you!

Comment: No hard feelings. GM:S is really a great program, and I hope you continue learning it :)